how to filter IQueryable from a list
So I have a model 'X' with a property of another model 'y' set on it and 'y' has an 'id' property.
I first define:
IQueryable<X> tempObject;

and initially populate with:
tempObject = (from b in _context.X.Include(v => v.y) select b);

Now I also pass in a List of id's and I want to filter tempObject to only include the records where 'y' id property is in the list.
I thought I might be able to do the following:
List<X> filter = new List<X>();

foreach(var id in myListofInt)
{
  var tt = tempObject.Where(b => b.y.Id == id).ToList();
  filter.addRange(tt);
}
tempObject = filter.AsQueryable<X>();

Although this doesn't give any initial error I receive a runtime error:

The source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncEnumerable'.
Only sources that implement 'IAsyncEnumerable' can be used for Entity
Framework asynchronous operations.

I'm struggling to figure out how to fix the above error.

Have you tried without the foreach loop? tempObject = tempObject.Where(b => myListofInt.Contains(b.y.Id);

THank you, this has worked. I did try something similar before but I had my contains against the wrong object type adn it wasn't allowed.

You could add a where clause to your original Linq query:
tempObject = from b in _context.X.Include(v => v.y) 
             where myListOfInts.Contains(b.y.Id)
             select b;


Try this:
tempObject = (from b in _context.X.Include(v => v.y) select b);

...

tempObject = tempObject.Where(x => myListofInt.Contains(x.y.Id));



Requirement: Given an IQueryable sequence of X objects, where every X has a property Y, and every Y has a property Id, and given an IEnumerable sequence of Ids, give me the IQueryable sequence of only those X objects, where the Id of its Y property equals one of the Ids in the enumerable sequence of Ids

In a relational database, you would have two tables in a one-to-many relation.
If you use entity framework, you would have classes like this:
class Address
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Street {get; set;}
    public int Number {get; set;}
    ... // other properties, like City, PostCode, Country, etc

    // on every Address live zero or more Students (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get; set;}
}

class Student
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    // every Student has exactly one Address using foreign key

    public int AddressId {get; set;}
    public virtual Address Address {get; set;}

    ... // other properties
}


In entity framework the non-virtual properties represent the columns in the tables, the virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many

So you have:
IQueryable<Student> students = ...
IEnumerable<int> addressIds = ...


Give me all Students that live on one of the Addresses represented by addressIds

Solution: use virtual property Student.Address
If you use entity framework, or something similar, you can use the virtual properties that represent the one-to-many relation. Entity framework knows the relations and will do the Join for you:
var studentsThatLiveInAddressIds = students.
    .Where(student => addressIds.Contains(student.Address.Id);

Consider to add a Select to transfer only the properties that you actually plan to use:
    .Select(student => new
    {
        Id = student.Id,
        Name = student.Name,

        Address = new
        {
            Id = student.Address.Id,
            Street = student.Address.Street,
            ... etc
        },
    };

Add a ToList to execute the query.
Do the Join yourself
If you can't use the virtual property, you have to do the Join yourself:
IQueryable<Student> students = ...
IQueryable<Address> addresses = ...
IEnumerable<int> addressIds = ...

var studentsThatLiveInAddressIds = students.Join(addresses,

// from every student take the foreign key to his Address:
student => student.AddressId,

// from every Address take the primary key
address => address.Id,

// parameter resultSelector
// when they match, take the student and his address to make one new:
(student, addressOfThisStudent) => new
{
    Id = student.Id,
    Name = student.Name,

    Address = new
    {
        Id = addressOfThisStudent.Id,
        Street = addressOfThisStudent.Street,
        ... etc
    })
    .ToList();

